# How to check Ethernet port connection status in Qt?

Tags: qt, ethernet, qudpsocket

I am new to Qt .Actually, i want to check Whether the Ethernet is connected or not through qt application.
For Example: when the Data is transfer from source to Destination through Ethernet. if i suddenly, remove the Ethernet cable my Qt application has to give some pop-up message like "the connection is unavailable". Is there any way to find this one? Finally,Sorry for my English.

Comment: Assuming you are not using raw ethernet frames to transfer the data, but use TCP/IP, then checking for status of network interfaces is probably not the right way to go. User could have VPN or PPP or WLAN connection too, user could switch networks, the destination computer could get unplugged from the network... You are more likely to create an annoyance for the user. Just trust the OS and Qt network handling, and report the errors you get from Qt for the particular *connection*.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to consider the Qt "Bearer Management" API:

http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/bearer-management.html

For example:

```
/ Set Internet Access Point
QNetworkConfigurationManager manager;
const bool canStartIAP = (manager.capabilities()
                          & QNetworkConfigurationManager::CanStartAndStopInterfaces);
// Is there default access point, use it
QNetworkConfiguration cfg = manager.defaultConfiguration();
if (!cfg.isValid() || (!canStartIAP && cfg.state() != QNetworkConfiguration::Active)) {
    QMessageBox::information(this, tr("Network"), tr(
                                 "No Access Point found."));
    return;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are on Linux, I found a nice idea somewhere to check with QT and QProcess if the Ethernet Cable is physically connected.

```
QProcess process;
QString sNetCableStatus = "";
process.start("sh", QStringList()<<"-c"<<"grep \"\" /sys/class/net/eth0/carrier");
process.waitForFinished();
sNetCableStatus = process.readAllStandardOutput();
if (sNetCableStatus.length() != 0)
{
    if (sNetCableStatus.left(1) == "1")
    {
        //connected
    }
    else if(sNetCableStatus.left(1) == "0")
    {
        //disconnected
    }
    else
    {
        //that should not happen
    }
}
```